# Python virtualenv isn't copying site packages (even with --system-site-packages flag)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, virtualenv

It seems that, when running virtualenv, none of the site packages get copied - even with the `--system-site-packages` flag.  The end goal is to make a relocatable copy.

I've looked at [virtualenv --system-site-packages not using system site packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239578/virtualenv-system-site-packages-not-using-system-site-packages), but unsetting PYTHONPATH didn't help.

Example:

```
$ python2.7
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 18 2013, 11:08:31) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>>

$ find /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages -name "*django*"
# Lots of files listed.

$ virtualenv-2.7 --system-site-packages django_branch

$ find ./django_branch/ -name "*django*"
# Nothing found.
```

I've also tried with the `--always-copy` flag and the `--python` flag and tried setting and unsetting PYTHONPATH, with no change.

```
$ setenv PYTHONPATH /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
$ setenv PYTHONPATH ''
```

Comment: This doesnt really address your question directly, but Virtualenvs arent really relocatable because of the inherrent symlink wiring.

Comment: Atleast from my understanding

Comment: Surely that's what the `--always-copy` flag is all about?