# Global Modules are not available in VirtualEnv

Tags: python, scipy, virtualenv

I'm using WinPython to work with libraries such as Scipy. I can not install those inside my virtual environment because blas/lapack is not available. The solution was to use the modules (theano/scipy/numpy) which are already installed on my system inside my virtual environment. 
Here is what I tried:

open console (cmd)

```
python
>>> import numpy
```

this works, now creating the virtual environment

```
set VIRTUALENV_PYTHON=C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\python-3.5.1.amd64\python.exe
set VIRTUALENV_EXTRA_SEARCH_DIR="C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\python-3.5.1.amd64\libs C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\python-3.5.1.amd64\Lib C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\python-3.5.1.amd64\DLLs C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\python-3.5.1.amd64\ C:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\python-3.5.1.amd64\Scripts"
virtualenv --system-site-packages -v --always-copy venv
```

or simply:

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages venv
```

but no matter what I try I can't import numpy when entering the venv.

```
venv\Scripts\activate
python
>>> import numpy
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Strange. So I compared the sys.path inside the venv:

```
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64', 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\Scripts', 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\DLLs', 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\Lib', 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\libs', 'C:\\Users\\user\\venv\\Scripts\\python35.zip', 'C:\\Users\\user\\venv\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\user\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\user\\venv\\Scripts', 'C:\\Users\\user\\venv', 'C:\\Users\\user\\venv\\lib\\site-pack
ages']
```

with the original one (outside):

```
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64', 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\Scripts', 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\DLLs', 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\Lib', 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\libs', 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\python35.zip', 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.1\\python-3.5.1.amd64\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

as you can see, not all the entries got copied over. Why is that and how can I fix it?

And yes I read [virtualenv --system-site-packages not using system site packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239578/virtualenv-system-site-packages-not-using-system-site-packages?rq=1) and deleted my PYTHONPATH variable but the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out eventually. I did not restart after removing my PYTHONPATH variable. So if you have the same issue:

1. Delete your PYTHONPATH env. variable.
2. Reboot!